# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1) and Out of memory on a 30720016-byte allocation

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I have encounter this error after running my app.

And before that there is a error message:

```
"Out of memory on a 30720016-byte allocation."
```

All my images are inside the `drawable` folder.

here's my code:

```
package com.androidteam.sg.easy.taxi.booking;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Declare our View variables and assign them the Views from the layout file
    Button getAnswerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button getAnswerButton1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button getAnswerButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button getAnswerButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button getAnswerButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button getAnswerButton5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    Button getAnswerButton6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    Button getAnswerButton7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);

    //Add PhoneStateListener
    PhoneCallListener phoneListener = new PhoneCallListener();
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephonyManager.listen(phoneListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    getAnswerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //The button was clicked, so update the answer by calling the number
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:65521111"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    getAnswerButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //The button was clicked, so update the answer label with answer
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:65521111"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    getAnswerButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //The button was clicked, so update the answer label with answer
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:6778 0808"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    getAnswerButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //The button was clicked, so update the answer label with answer
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:6363 0808"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    getAnswerButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //The button was clicked, so update the answer label with answer
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:6485 7777"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    getAnswerButton5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //The button was clicked, so update the answer label with answer
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:6555 8888"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    getAnswerButton6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //The button was clicked, so update the answer label with answer
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:6555 3333"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    getAnswerButton7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //The button was clicked, so update the answer label with answer
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:6293 5545"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}



//monitor phone call activities

private class PhoneCallListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    private boolean isPhoneCalling = false;

    String LOG_TAG = "LOGGING 123";

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING == state) {
            // phone ringing
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "RINGING, number: " + incomingNumber);
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK == state) {
            // active
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "OFFHOOK");

            isPhoneCalling = true;
        }

        if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE == state) {
            // run when class initial and phone call ended, 
            // need detect flag from CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "IDLE");

            if (isPhoneCalling) {

                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "restart app");

                // restart app
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                    .getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                        getBaseContext().getPackageName());
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

                isPhoneCalling = false;
            }

        }
    }
}


}
```

Please how to resolve the error messages.

Comment: Show us the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

This happens if your image sizes are too big to fit in the heap of the application. Heap for an android app is 16MB from android 4.2. Probably your images are too big so they can not fit in the heap memory and you are getting an outofmemory error. But from the code it doesn't seem like you are using any images in the code. So if you are trying to show high quality images in your app make sure you also have image for low screen resolution devices in the folders 
drawable-hdpi , drawable-ldpi , drawable-xhdpi , drawable-mdpi.